# Google Drive API Export GAS file specific version

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am currently trying to bring some order to our Google App Script files and develop a HTMLService app that finds and parses GAS files in Google Drive and produces API documentation based on jsdoc style comments.

I have the WebApp functional and can pull all the data I need and parse the comments but by default it exports the current GAS file contents, regardless of if it's published or not.

What I would like to do is pull the contents of the latest Saved Version rather than the current dev content, is there a way I can specify a version to export?
I am using a `URLFetch()` to get the content, as per below:

```js
var params = {
    headers:{
      'Accept':'application/vnd.google-apps.script+json', 
      'Authorization':'Bearer '+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }, 
    method:'get'
  };
  
  var fileDrive = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  var link = JSON.parse(fileDrive)['exportLinks']['application/vnd.google-apps.script+json'];
  var fetched = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link, params);
  return { meta: fileDrive, source: JSON.parse(fetched.getContentText()) };
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions), each change is referred to as a "Revision" and access to revisions is provided through the Revisions resource. You can programmatically save new revisions of a file or **query the version history** as detailed in the [Revisions reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions).

**[Listing revisions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_revisions)**

> The following example demonstrates how to list the revisions for a given file. Note that some properties of revisions are only available for certain file types. For example, G Suite application files do not consume space in Google Drive and thus return a file size of `0`.
>
> ```
> function listRevisions(fileId) {
>   var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
>   if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 0) {
>     for (var i = 0; i < revisions.items.length; i++) {
>       var revision = revisions.items[i];
>       var date = new Date(revision.modifiedDate);
>       Logger.log('Date: %s, File size (bytes): %s', date.toLocaleString(),
>           revision.fileSize);
>     }
>   } else {
>     Logger.log('No revisions found.');
>   }
> }
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks unfortunately for scripts it gives an error `File does not support revisions`
Also just reading Importing/Exporting Scripts and noticed this...
_Actions such as script versioning, publishing or executing the script are not possible via the Google Drive REST API_
So not looking hopeful